# Ruby warns about NameError while prepend Gtk modules to Object class

Tags: ruby, gtk, gtk3

I am using the Gtk3 gem. Following is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'gtk3'

class Object
    prepend Gtk
end

Application.new('org.gtk.example')
```

Result:

> /home/sourav/gtk.rb:8:in `<main>': uninitialized constant `Application` (`NameError`)

But the following code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'gtk3'

class Object
    prepend Gtk
    Gtk::Application
end

Application.new('org.gtk.example')
```

This doesn't have to be specifically `Gtk::Application`, it could be `::Gtk::ApplicationWindow` under the prepend line. Why am I getting `NameError` without the `Gtk::Application` line?

Comment: I suggest you add a tag "Gtk" and change the title to "...prepend Gtk...", so that readers, like myself, who know nothing of the gem, are not lured into reading a question that is of no interest and which they cannot hope to answer.

Comment: Wild guess: because [tag:ruby] never promised autoloading of everything. I am pretty sure that `::Gtk::Application.new('org.gtk.example')` in the first snippet would work. Also, I am not sure I understand what is the exact purpose of prepending `Gtk` to `Object`, while it might bring a lot of harm.

Comment: Prepending or including Gtk will be added to the Object class. You can directly write include ::Gtk without having to write <class Object ; include Gtk ; end> - but you can't directly use prepend keyword. Say you want to access ApplicationWindow, you will write Gtk::ApplicationWindow, but by including it, you will write only ApplicationWindow. Consider: `module A class B define_singleton_method(:c) do "From #{self}" end end end ; include A ; p B.c`. This saves a bit of time. You don't have to write A::B.c every time. That's it. There's no other reason.